# WordPress неправильный порядок отображения меню

Tags: wordpress, menu

Отображает меню не в правильном порядке
Какие причины этому? Сайт сделан на  WordPress. Если нужны стили , закину.Сайт вот http://intellect-media.biz/

```
 <header id="masthead" class="site-header">
    <div class="site-branding">
    <?php the_custom_logo();
    if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>
    <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
    <?php else : ?>
    <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
    <?php endif;
     $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
     if ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
    <p class="site-description"><?php echo $description; /* WPCS: xss ok. */ ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- .site-branding -->
    <div class="header__bottom">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row sm-flex">
          <div class="col-sm-3 clearfix">
            </div>                 
              <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation col-sm-9">
       <a href="/" class="header__bottom__logo">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/method-draw-image.svg" alt="logo"/>
      </a> 
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#header__bottom__nav" aria-expanded="false" >
       <span class="sr-only"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
       <div class="header__bottom__nav collapse navbar-collapse"  id="header__bottom__nav" >
         <div class="header__bottom__nav__item"> 
        <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
            'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
        ) ); ?></div>
     </div>
       </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
          </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: В админке можно перетягивать пункты меню в нужном порядке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы поставили

```
li {
  float: right;
}
```

Это как раз и меняет порядок следования элементов меню - задом наперёд.

Видимо, хотели все меню вправо прижать. Надо так:

```
ul {
  float: right;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
```